# A celery task called twice modifying one object

Tags: django, celery, task-queue

I'm experimenting with celery to understand how it works. I've written a simple worker, which modifies an array:

```
from .celery import app
import time

arr = []
status = 'waiting'

@app.task
def push_back(val):
    global arr
    if status == 'busy':
        return 'try later'
    status = 'busy'
    arr.append(val)
    time.sleep(5)
    status = 'waiting'
    return arr
```

And here is my client:

```
from proj.tasks import push_back
from sys import argv

res = push_back.delay(int(argv[1]))
data = res.get()
print(data)
```

I call the client twice, one immediately after the other with different arguments.
E.g. my call is:

```
python3 update_object.py 3 &
python3 update_object.py 5
```

The responses are [3] and [5], respectively.

I have another task for checking the state of the array, which returns [3], so only the first call has made any effect.

Could somebody explain what exactly is going on during such a call?
Why is the status not checked?
Why does the second call modify the array?

My ultimate goal is to implement Django API and an AI server being a celery worker. Besides predictions, I also want to load different models (modify the state) using remote calls from Django. I want to disable the task execution if it has been called by another user. Is celery a good choice for that? What are your recommendations?